# CSS How to make dropdown items appear on top

Tags: html, css

I have found some code on the internet that i really like.  It is using CSS to create a cool looking dropdown menu.  While it works, the problem is when I have multiple of these controls underneath of each other.  With having multiple dropdowns below, the actual dropdown list will not appear on top of other dropdowns below.  Here is my code:

```
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3">
        <span id="spTransport">Transport</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Classic mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>UPS Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Private jet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="dd2" class="wrapper-dropdown-3">
        <span id="spTransport2">Transport</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Classic mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>UPS Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Private jet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="dd3" class="wrapper-dropdown-3">
        <span id="spTransport3">Transport</span>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope icon-large"></i>Classic mail</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-truck icon-large"></i>UPS Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-plane icon-large"></i>Private jet</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
::selection {
    background: transparent; 
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent; 
}
/*
.wrapper-demo {
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    *zoom: 1;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.wrapper-demo:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
*/
/* DEMO 3 */

.wrapper-dropdown-3 {
    /* Size and position */
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    padding: 3px;

    /* Styles */
    /*background: #fff;*/
    background: #3E3E47;
    border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;

    /* Font settings */
    font-weight: bold;
    /*color: #8AA8BD;*/
    color: white;

    opacity:.99;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    /*border-color: #8aa8bd transparent;*/
    border-color: white transparent;

    opacity:.99;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
  /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 140%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    /* Styles */
    background: black;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: normal;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    list-style: none;

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;



    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 15px;
    border-width: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000 transparent;    



    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 13px;
    border-width: 0 8px 8px 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) transparent;    




    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    /*color: #8aa8bd;*/
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e8ea;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li i {
    float: right;
    color: inherit;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:first-of-type a {
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:last-of-type a {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0 0 7px 7px;
}

/* Hover state */

.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li:hover a {
    /*background: #f3f8f8;*/
    /*background: #3A3A49;*/
    background: #3E3E47;
}

/* Active state */

.wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* No CSS3 support */

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1; /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
    pointer-events: auto; /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity       .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .wrapper-dropdown-3.active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I make the dropdown items appear overtop of the main dropdown controls below the one clicked on?  So if I click on the first dropdown, the "li" items appear, but they appear underneath of the dropdown div's below the one clicked.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/36evU/

Thanks in advance,

Brad

Comment: Is javascript or jquery allowed ?

Comment: No need for js and jquery here. The code provided doesn't work for any dropdown http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/36evU/

Comment: Can you give a link where you found this code, would be realy helpfull.

Comment: i guess you just have a lil problem with your `z-index` but why you post a not working fiddle ? does the dropdown works on your pc?

Comment: Here is the link where I found the code:

Comment: sorry, http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

Comment: I am guessing it would have something to do with z-index, but tried to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

there is an option drop down menu horizontal true hope my example will help
**HTML**

```
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">main</a></li>
        <li><a href="">company</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">works</a></li>
                <li><a href="">clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="">partners</a></li>
                <li><a href="">menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="">social</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 20px;
}
/*Горизонтальное выпадающее меню*/
ul.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#4f4f4f), to(#2b2b2b));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#4f4f4f, #2b2b2b);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4f4f4f', endColorstr='#2b2b2b', GradientType=0); 
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    width: 900px;
}

ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    position: relative;
}

ul.menu li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 8px 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

ul.menu li:first-child a:hover {
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
/*Выпадающее меню*/
ul.menu li ul {
    display: none;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 34px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    z-index: 1000;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 150px;
    border-right: none;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul li a {
    border-top: 1px solid #4f4f4f;
    border-right: none;
    padding: 6px 20px 8px;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #c1deff;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul li:first-child a:hover {
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
}
```

[demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HLKkz)